# Search bar is not returning the expected results

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, search

I am trying to make a search bar to search for users in my app. I have created a method to do that that works just fine in ASP .NET

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<MemberDto>> Search(string content)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
            {
                return await _context.Users.ProjectTo<MemberDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
            }

            return _context.Users.Where(e => e.UserName.StartsWith(content) ||
                                             e.FirstName.StartsWith(content) ||
                                             e.LastName.StartsWith(content) ||
                                             (e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName).StartsWith(content))
                .ProjectTo<MemberDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
        }
```

```
       [HttpGet("search")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MemberDto>>> SearchUser([FromQuery] string content)
        {
            var users = await _userRepository.Search(content);

            return Ok(users);
        }
```

In my home page I have created a search bar with a search button. After writing a string I want to be able to press on the search button to return all the matching users in another page. However, I am not able to figure out how to do that. This is my method:

```
search(content: string) {
    this.memberService.search(content).pipe(
      map((response: Member[]) => {
        const usernames = response.length;
        (term => term === '' ? [] : usernames);
      }),
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged())
      console.log(content);
  }
```

My method in the member service is:

```
search(content: string) {
    return this.http.get<Member[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users/search?content=' + content);
  }
```

And this is my html:

```
<form class="example" (ngSubmit)="search(model.content)" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
        <input id="typeahead-format" name="content" [(ngModel)]="model.content" type="text" class="ml-2 
         form-control" placeholder="Caută utilizatori"/>
        <button class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" routerLink="search?= 
         {{model.content}}" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

I am also getting an error in vendor.js and main.js `TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestContent' of undefined`
What am I doing wrong in the TypeScript method? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
search(content: string) {
this.memberService.search(content).subscribe(response: Member[] => {
const usernames = response;
term = term === '' ? [] : usernames;
}),
  debounceTime(200),
  distinctUntilChanged())
  console.log(content);
}
```

HTML code for searchbar

```
<input placeholder="Search" (keyup)="search(model.content)">
```

Code to check whether members is returned

```
search(content: string) {
const data = this.http.get<Member[]>(this.baseUrl + 'users/search? 
content=' + content);
console.log(data);
return data;
}
```

AutoComplete

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
<mat-option *ngFor="let username of usernames" [value]="option">
{{username}}
</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: As of  'requestContent' of undefined show the code containing 'requestContent'

Comment: Thank you for answering. The requestContent error disappeared. The search bar works better now, but it filters only the names I have already searched, not the names of all usernames. The line `const usernames = response.length"` is not well written. I wanted to extract the usernames of all members and filter through that, not through the response length.

Comment: Oh there was a mistake in my code. I have edited it. 'term ===' was wrong. It is 'term ='

Comment: As of username try this:  const usernames = response; assuming response is an array. Array.length returns length of the array.

Comment: I made the changes and I added this in my html search button: `<button class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" (input)="search(model.content)" routerLink="search/{{model.content}}"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>`. The function is not even called when I am typing in my searchbar. I have also tried (keyUp), (keyPress) and (change) but with no success

Comment: If you want to search while typing, the element should be <input> I have edited the answer. Check it.

Comment: This is my code now `searchText(content: string) {
    this.memberService.search(content).pipe(
      map((response: Member[]) => {
        const usernames = response;
        (term => term = '' ? [] : usernames);
      }),
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged())
      console.log(content);
  }` and `<input id="typeahead-format" name="content" (keyup)="searchText(model.content)" [(ngModel)]="model.content" type="text" class="ml-2 form-control"/>` but it still doesn't work as intended

Comment: This is not similar to the code I have given. Try with the code I have given

Comment: Yes, sorry. I copied your code but it still doesn't work. The page loads on every keyup, but without showing results

Comment: Just check if the http is returning the member list. Put a console.log() before returning and check in the console.

Comment: This is the output in the console: `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`

Comment: Ok, seems like no problem there. Now check in the network tab for the particular get request. Check the response. Check whether members are returned in the response.

Comment: Yes, the members are returned in the response

Comment: Can you share the response, just to check the format. Also share the code where you are using the 'term' variable

Comment: And I am really sorry about the term variable. It should be term = term === '' ? [] : usernames. Try with that. Hope that works. Is the term variable declared globally?

Comment: Thank you for responding, it still doesn't seem to work ok. This is the code `search(content: string) {
    this.memberService.search(content).subscribe((response: Member[]) => {
      const usernames = response;
      (term => term === '' ? [] : usernames);
      }),
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged()
      console.log(content);
  }` and this is the response for input "mad"`[{"id":5,"userName":"maddy","photoUrl":null,"firstName":"Maddy","lastName":"Lee","email":"madlee@yahoo.com","age":43,"created":"2021-02-20T14:36:43.186932","photo":null}]` .

Comment: Term is not declared globally

Comment: Isn't term using for display somewhere. I mean in templates maybe.

Comment: 1. Write the line 'term = term === '' ? [] : usernames'. No arrow mark. I actually want the code that is used for dispaying the searched items.

Comment: 2. Declare term in the class level in the ts file.

Comment: Ok so this is the code(i declared term globally) `search(content: string) {
    this.memberService.search(content).subscribe((response: Member[]) => {
      const usernames = response;
      this.term = this.term === '' ? [] : usernames;
      }),
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged()
      console.log(content);
  }` this is the template `<input id="typeahead-format" name="content" (keyup)="search(model.content)" [(ngModel)]="model.content" type="text" class="ml-2 form-control"/>`

Comment: The page also reloads after every letter that I'm writing, which is not desired

Comment: Ok now show the code where term is used for displaying the member list.

Comment: and regarding loading, keyup will trigger a new event every time you types a key. Do you just want the search to happen only when a button is clicked or something like that?

Comment: I want the valid results to appear as suggestions beneath the search bar, the way they appear in a Facebook search bar for example. I want some sort of filtering, like an autocomplete

Comment: Okay, first we can solve the display problem. Are the values still not displaying?  Also please share the code where the term is being used to display. In the given code, it only shows the term is assigned a value and after that the term is unused.

Comment: I am not using term, I supposed it was the text I was writing in the search bar. If I press enter on the search bar, the results are showing now in a new page, but the search bar does not filter through the users

Comment: OK, then share the code that is used to display the members.

Comment: This is in the search page component: `ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log(params);
      this.content = params['content'];
    });

    this.search();
  }

  search() {
    this.memberService.search(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('content')).subscribe((response: Member[]) => {
      this.members = response;
      console.log(response);
    })
  }`

Comment: And this is in the navbar component: `search(content: string) {
    this.memberService.search(content).subscribe((response: Member[]) => {
      const usernames = response;
      this.term = this.term === '' ? [] : usernames;
      }),
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged()
      console.log(content);
  }`. When I press enter in the search bar(in the nav bar) it redirects me to the search page component.

Comment: I think you need an auto complete. Try mat-auto-complete. Link: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: Yes, something like this. But how do I make use of term? `<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let member of members | async" [label]="member.username">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let term of member.username" [value]="term">
              {{term}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-optgroup>
        </mat-autocomplete>

        <input type="text"
       placeholder="Search users"
       aria-label="User"
       matInput
       [matAutocomplete]="auto">`  Like this?

Comment: At first check whether term is receiving value by console.log() and try with edited answer

Comment: Term is undefined and the autocomplete is not even showing. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: Getting irritated? Did you import matautocomplete into the ng module?

Comment: Not really, I am just missing the problem. Yes, I've imported matautocomplete

Comment: Sorry for late reply

Comment: Is it okay now?

Comment: I will try building a similar thing in stackblitz